# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysha3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: pyproject.toml

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYCEk.png]

I don't have to much coding experience, but was trying to install python package py_clob_client to use the polymarket api, I'm getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That include file says it doesn't exist .. is it not there?  pystrhex.h  <--- please for the love of God, copy the text and post it .. pictures just are a pain in the bum for fixing errors.

Comment: pysha3 package is deprecated, you should use safe-pysha3 instead which is compatible with newer Python version. https://github.com/5afe/pysha3